# Postgresql join with Condition

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have three table as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    password character varying(128) NOT NULL,
    username character varying(15) NOT NULL,
    email character varying(100) NULL,
    gender character varying(1) NOT NULL  
  );


CREATE TABLE followers (
    id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    followed_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    follower_id uuid REFERENCES users(id),
    following_id uuid REFERENCES users(id)
  );


CREATE TABLE profile_picture (
    id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    profile_pic character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    owner_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
    is_active boolean NOT NULL
  );
```

I want the query for selecting all the follower with the fields : `id, username and active_profile_pic`.

`is_active` will be true only for one profile pic of the user but he can upload as many profile photo as he want.

I have tried the without profile_pic, which is not the wanted result.

```
select users.id , username from users inner join followers on follower_id = users.id where followers.following_id = user_id;
```

I want the query for selecting all the followers with id, username and active_profile_pic who are following the user with given user_id.

User may have no profile pic and can have more than one so only the active_profile pic should be returned.

Query will have to contain the follower with no profile picture too.

Tried this, but it is not returning follower which have no profile picture. I want to return that too.

```
SELECT u.id, username, p.profile_pic  FROM followers INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = follower_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN profile_picture AS p ON u.id = p.owner_id
where followers.following_id = '' and p.is_active = true
```

In the above query `user_id` signifies variable , you can specify id of the user there.

Please visit [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c028bea6f08d8c1557650b9de0105740)

Please suggest me the right query.

Comment: your create code produces lots of errors

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want all users with a profile pic that are following someone, *or* all users that are following at least one person who has a profile pic, or something else? Sample data and expected output would help a lot, ideally with an [mcve] on https://dbfiddle.uk or similar.

Comment: Updated the question, please recheck.

Comment: see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c028bea6f08d8c1557650b9de0105740) => it still has errors....

Comment: user_id is a variable you can specify id of the user there.

Comment: then why not to, ad in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1538a68d548dd405432bc7ce1df60942)?  This will not produce an error. But also not data because of the missing data in this sample. Some data might make this question more clear.

Comment: I have added the data, please check @Luuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have profile_picture.is_active test in WHERE condition, therefore your result will display only users with profile picture set. If you want all users, regardless of the profile picture, you should include profile_picture.is_active column in query results and delete the condition p.is_active = true from WHERE statement.

Comment: Please check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=84cf48afc21eaebef8582c04e525e129

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @random_user,

This works for me.

```
select id , username, profile_pic from (SELECT u.id, username, is_active, profile_pic  FROM users as u Full Outer JOIN followers  ON u.id = follower_id
Full Outer JOIN profile_picture AS p ON u.id = p.owner_id
where followers.following_id = '2582f93d-68c3-48e2-98ba-a401402c7b62') as profile_table where (is_active = true) or (is_active is null)
```

May be someone can suggest, better answer, but this works for me.

Check it at [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8cbf8316988c085799ba101499987f7a)